# How to run the command working in command prompt form python shell?

Tags: python, shell

Program [ex13.py]:

```
import sys
a = raw_input("Input 3rd variable:")
print "The script is called:", sys.argv[0]
print "Your first variable is:", sys.argv[1]
print "Your second variable is:", sys.argv[2]
print "Your third variable is:", a
```

Executing in command prompt:
ex13.py 1 3

How to run this from the python shell by giving the argv ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the output you can do this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(os.path.dirname("python ex13.py 1 3", shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

output = process.communicate()
exit_code = process.wait();
```